# text tracks on vimeo platform using c#

Tags: c#, vimeo

I'm writing a program that uploads videos on Vimeo platform. It works fine, no problems for this. Now I need to upload subtitles in different languages linked to videos as well, and I didn't find any example (in c#) to do that.
Does somebody already met this problem and solved it? Is there any chance to have a working example in c#?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Usually, you will need to show relevant parts of your code and whatever errors you may be getting. Asking people for libraries and such is not the purpose of this site. Basically, you will have a question that is focused and has actual code that people can look at while trying to help.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. That's the problem: I don't have any error since I don't know how to write the code to link subtitles to videos on Vimeo. I can upload a video without problems but I don't know how to upload subtitles in language to each video.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I found the way to do that:

public void SetSubtitles(string videoId, string fileName)
{
var uri = String.Format("https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{0}/texttracks", videoId);
var res = DoGenericHttpCall("POST", uri, "", "", null, HttpStatusCode.Created, true);
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res,
new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
SendPicture(x.link, fileName);
uri = String.Format("https://api.vimeo.com{0}", x.uri);

```
        var t0 = Environment.TickCount;
        bool repeat = true;
        while (repeat)
        {
            try
            {
                string videoInfo = "";
                videoInfo = videoInfo + string.Format("language={0}", "it");
                videoInfo = videoInfo + "&" + string.Format("type={0}", "subtitles");
                videoInfo = videoInfo + "&" + string.Format("name={0}", "Italian");

                //DoGenericHttpCall("PATCH", uri, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "active=true", null, HttpStatusCode.OK);
                DoGenericHttpCall("PATCH", uri, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", videoInfo, null, HttpStatusCode.OK);
                repeat = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                repeat = ((Environment.TickCount - t0) < 10000);
                if (repeat)
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                else
                    throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```